# Group titles for matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I use a [GridSpec](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html) within matplotlib to trying to generate the following plot:

[image: Desired result]

However I fail at adding the titles at the desired positions, which are at the top center of each two columns. The following code creates the plot above sans titles:

```
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)
gs = fig.add_gridspec(2, 6)

for i in range(0, 6, 2):
    fig.add_subplot(gs[:, i])
    fig.add_subplot(gs[0, i + 1])
    fig.add_subplot(gs[1, i + 1])
```

Adding the following two lines creates the titles but also creates a figure above the other figures:

```
    title = fig.add_subplot(gs[:, i:i + 2])
    title.set_title(f'title #{i}')
```

How do I have to change the given code to get the desired result depicted above? Is there a way to hide the new figures? Is there a way to set titles/text without figures?

Comment: Thats something we hope to have in 3.4.

Comment: Whats the new feature's name?

Comment: It’s the subpanel feature discussed here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/17437

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One variant is to hide the newly added figures but their titles
Adding this line to the proposed other two, the plot looks like desired:

```
    title.set_axis_off()
```

Therefore the full script would look like this:

```
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)
gs = fig.add_gridspec(2, 6)

for i in range(0, 6, 2):
    fig.add_subplot(gs[:, i])
    fig.add_subplot(gs[0, i + 1])
    fig.add_subplot(gs[1, i + 1])
    title = fig.add_subplot(gs[:, i:i + 2])
    title.set_title(f'title #{i}')
    title.set_axis_off()
```